# How to catch a selected option from a <SELECT> in MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(string id, FormCollection formCollection, bool cart = false)
    {

        ProductDbContext pdb = new ProductDbContext();
        Product product = pdb.getProductbyNaam(id);
        ProductVM pvm = new ProductVM();
        pvm.extrakosten = 0;
        pvm.product = product;
        pvm.added2cart = cart;
        if (pvm.product == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (formCollection != null)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < formCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                String value = formCollection[i];
                pvm.extrakosten = +pdb.getSubOptieByTekst(value.ToString()).prijs;
            }

        }
        return View(pvm);
    }
```

Now this is my cshtml code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Checkout", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
{
                {
                    foreach (var optie in Model.product.opties)
                    {
                        if (optie.dropdown)
                        {
                            int count = 0;
                            int counttotaal = 0;
                            foreach (Originalz.Models.SubOptie so in optie.dropdownopties)
                            {


                                if (count == 0)
                                {
                                    counttotaal++;
                                    @Html.Raw("<dt>")
                                    @Html.DisplayName(optie.beschrijving)
                                    @Html.Raw("</dt>")
                                    @Html.Raw("<dd>")
                                    @Html.Raw("<select id=option" + counttotaal + " name=option" + counttotaal + ">");

                                }
                                @Html.Raw("<option value=\"" + so.id + "\">");
                                @Html.Encode(so.optietekst);
                                @Html.Raw("</option>");
                                count++;
                                if (count == optie.dropdownopties.Count)
                                {
                                    @Html.Raw("</select>");
                                    @Html.Raw("</dd>")
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", null, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" })
}
```

I want to get the selected option from the select in my `ActionResult`.
`formCollection` is always empty/null by the way, and it doesn't even enter my `postMethod`, probably because `formCollection` is not given and it just takes my normal get Method:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id, bool cart = false)

    {
        ProductDbContext pdb = new ProductDbContext();
        Product product = pdb.getProductbyNaam(id);
        ProductVM pvm = new ProductVM();
        pvm.extrakosten = 0;
        pvm.product = product;
        pvm.added2cart = cart;
        if(pvm.product == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pvm);
    }
```

I might just be misunderstanding the `formCollection`, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using ViewModel instead FormCollection? It would be a lot easier. For rendering list you can use @Html.DropDownListFor

Comment: The problem is that I couldnt get that to work either somehow, I was really having problems with the selectlists

Comment: You don't have a submit button on you form, maybe thats why it doesn't enter Details method

Comment: you are overcomplicating things, please use strongly typed view and use strongly typed html helper

Comment: it's not going to hit an Action name DETAILS if your form is telling it to post to Cart.Checkout `@using (Html.BeginForm("Checkout", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: Jamie, thanks man, I cant believe ive looked over something this stupid...

Comment: i recommend using Fiddler or something similar when you're debugging MVC.. it will point these things out right away